# Invite people to a slack channel via PHP

Tags: php, json, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to build a tiny routine in which someone could create a new channel and invite users automatically to that new channel.

I am using the simple Web-Api and so my Code just looks like this:

```
https://slack.com/api/channels.create?token=[TOKEN]&name=testchannel
```

This works, but now I want to receive a list of all the channels to invite people to the new channel – okay, obviously I just need the ID of the new channel.

I tried this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://slack.com/api/channels.list?token=[TOKEN]&pretty=1');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);
    echo $obj->channels;

    foreach ($obj as $objects) {
      echo $objects, "\n";
    }
```

I not so familiar with JSON, so I'm stuck right now.

Comment: If you want to deal with `$obj->channels` then maybe that's what you should iterate over.

Comment: That `$obj = json_decode($result);
$test = $obj->channels;

foreach ($test as $objects) {
    echo $objects, "\n";
}` gives me an error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

Comment: Tip: Use [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for arbitrary PHP objects.

Comment: mmh, I maybe have found a way … thanks for the iteration clue

Comment: @18zehn If you found the solution it would be nice if you could post it as answer and mark it. So that we can close this question. thank you!

Comment: @ErikKalkoken I wil as soon as I found a solution … I hope